# Update query in same stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert-update

I want to write the logic of `UPDATE` for the same table in same stored procedure. Below is my SP.

```html
PROCEDURE INSERT_PROJECT_MST
(
  P_PROJECTNO IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_CRNO IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_APPNAME IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_APPFUNCDESC IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_AZUREFEATNO IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_AZUREFEATDESC IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_PROJMANAGER IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_PROJLEAD IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_REQBY IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_BUSINESSCAT IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_BUSINESSUSERCAT IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_FEATUREID IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_ISMGISRNO IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_REPLICARR IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_PRODRR IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_USERSTORY IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_ASSIGNEDBY IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_ASSIGNEDTO IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_CREATEDBY IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_LASTUPDBY IN NVARCHAR2,
  TBLDATA OUT NVARCHAR2
)
AS
  
  V_PROJ_ID NUMBER:=0;
  
  BEGIN
    
   -- SELECT COUNT(MST_ID) INTO V_PROJ_ID FROM TBL_PROJECT_MST_INFO WHERE PROJECT_NO = P_PROJECTNO;
   
   INSERT INTO TBL_PROJECT_MST_INFO      
                                   (
                                          PROJECT_NO,
                                          CR_NO,
                                          APPLICATION_NAME,
                                          APP_FUNC_DESC,
                                          AZURE_FEATURE_NO,
                                          AZURE_FEATURE_DESC,
                                          PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME,
                                          PROJECT_LEAD_NAME,
                                          REQUESTED_BY,
                                          BUSINESS_CATEGORY,
                                          BUSINESS_USER_CATEGORY,
                                          RATIONAL_FEATURE_ID,
                                          ISMG_ISR_NO,
                                          REPLICA_RR,
                                          PROD_RR,
                                          USER_STORY,
                                          ASSIGNED_BY,
                                          ASSIGNED_TO,
                                          CREATED_BY,
                                          LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                          CREATED_DATE,
                                          LAST_UPDATED_DATE
                                    )
                                     VALUES
                                   (            
                                          P_PROJECTNO,
                                          P_CRNO,
                                          P_APPNAME,
                                          P_APPFUNCDESC,
                                          P_AZUREFEATNO,
                                          P_AZUREFEATDESC,
                                          P_PROJMANAGER,
                                          P_PROJLEAD,
                                          P_REQBY,
                                          P_BUSINESSCAT,
                                          P_BUSINESSUSERCAT,
                                          P_FEATUREID,
                                          P_ISMGISRNO,
                                          P_REPLICARR,
                                          P_PRODRR,
                                          P_USERSTORY,
                                          UPPER(P_ASSIGNEDBY),
                                          UPPER(P_ASSIGNEDTO),
                                          P_CREATEDBY,
                                          P_LASTUPDBY,
                                          SYSDATE,
                                          SYSDATE
                                   )                                   
                                   
                                   RETURNING V_PROJ_ID INTO TBLDATA;
          TBLDATA:='Record Saved Succesfully';  
          
END  INSERT_PROJECT_MST;
```

Also below is the table description for the same.

```html
Name                   Null     Type           
---------------------- -------- -------------- 
ID                              NUMBER         
MST_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER         
PROJECT_NO                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
CR_NO                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
APPLICATION_NAME                NVARCHAR2(255) 
APP_FUNC_DESC                   CLOB           
AZURE_FEATURE_NO                NVARCHAR2(155) 
AZURE_FEATURE_DESC              CLOB           
PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME            NVARCHAR2(100) 
PROJECT_LEAD_NAME               NVARCHAR2(100) 
REQUESTED_BY                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
BUSINESS_CATEGORY               NVARCHAR2(100) 
BUSINESS_USER_CATEGORY          NVARCHAR2(100) 
RATIONAL_FEATURE_ID             NVARCHAR2(100) 
ISMG_ISR_NO                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
REPLICA_RR                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
PROD_RR                         NVARCHAR2(100) 
USER_STORY                      NVARCHAR2(500) 
CREATED_BY                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
CREATED_DATE                    DATE           
ASSIGNED_TO                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
ASSIGNED_BY                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
IS_ACTIVE                       CHAR(1)        
LAST_UPDATED_BY                 NVARCHAR2(100) 
LAST_UPDATED_DATE               DATE           
COLUMN3                         VARCHAR2(20)   
COLUMN4                         VARCHAR2(20)   
COLUMN5                         VARCHAR2(20)
```

**NOTE** `MST_ID` is my unique identity column based on which I will update the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you are asking. Currently, your procedure inserts a row into a table; values you insert are procedure's IN parameters.

You'd want to be able to update current rows in the same table, by calling the same procedure and passing the same parameters?

If so, **MERGE** might be a good choice. It is also called an *upsert* as it is capable of inserting rows (which don't exist) or update rows (if they exist) in the same table.

Something like this (simplified; didn't feel like typing that many columns):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_project_mst (p_mst_id     IN     NUMBER,
                                               p_projectno  IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                               p_crno       IN     NVARCHAR2,
                                               p_msg           OUT NVARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO tbl_project_mst_info t
        USING (SELECT p_mst_id, p_projectno, p_crno FROM DUAL) x
           ON (x.p_mst_id = t.mst_id)
   WHEN MATCHED
   THEN
      UPDATE SET t.project_no = p_projectno, t.cr_no = p_crno
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
   THEN
      INSERT     (mst_id, project_no, cr_no)
          VALUES (x.p_mst_id, x.p_projectno, x.p_crno);

   p_msg := 'Merged ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' row(s)';
END;
```

Comment: no issues about writing the columns, but will it update if the records exists and insert when not ?

Comment: while inserting `INSERT     (mst_id, project_no, cr_no)` mst_id is my unique column. it will insert automatically

Comment: **1**st comment: try and you'll see. **2**nd comment: if you want to be able to update existing rows, you'll have to pass MST_ID as a parameter. How else will you know which row(s) to update?

Comment: I want to return a successfull insert or update msg.. how will I add it ? please suggest

Comment: Include an OUT parameter; I modified sample code, have a look.

Comment: getting error as `{"ORA-00904: \"X\".\"P_MST_ID\": invalid identifier\nORA-06512: at \"APP_WFM.MERGE_PROJECT_MST\", line 25\nORA-06512: at line 1"}` while inserting new records

Comment: It means that there's no column with that name in a table. Check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222015/discussion-between-hud-and-littlefoot).